# Is there a way to use TextWrangler to clean-up / tidy messy XML?

Tags: xml

I don't need it to validate ( though that would be nice  I don't think text wrangler does this) but to clean up messy .xml.

example this ...

```
<some><foo>
bar</foo></some>
```

to ...

```
<some>
   <foo>bar</foo>
</some>
```

thanks -MW

Answer (score 6):

If you're after a tool, most editors have some sort of "Tidy" feature.

- In NotePad++: TestFX -> TestFX HTML Tidy -> Tidy: Reindent XML
- In Visual Studio: Ctrl-K, Ctrl-D (or Edit -> Advanced -> Format Document)

A quick google for TextWrangler turns up this - http://magp.ie/2010/02/15/format-xml-with-textwrangler/

Comment: thanks for the advise + link. After several attempts, I can't seem to get it going. keep getting a (MacOS Error code: -1409) .

Comment: The TextWrangler instructions work, but are missing the following steps. 1) quit and restart TextWrangler to register the Unix script 2) select the text you want to format before running the script

Comment: Also note that you should currently save the file in `~/Library/Application Support/TextWrangler/Text Filters/`

Comment: This snippet of code works for me: `#!/bin/sh \n
XMLLINT_INDENT=$'\t' xmllint --format --encode utf-8` (notice I included a \n for linebreak for your benefit, please replace)

Comment: To support jcolebrand's comment I invite everyone to visit the solution for TextWrangler 4.0 at http://www.bergspot.com/blog/2012/05/getting-xml-tidy-xmllint-to-work-on-textwrangler-4-0/

Answer (score 3):

As an update to the instructions from http://magp.ie/2010/02/15/format-xml-with-textwrangler/ and the comment by @Cykoduck for getting this to work in TextWrangler version 4.

The script needs to be changed to take the input from STDIN instead of a temporary file, so the first invocation of `xmllint` needs to be changed:

```
#!/bin/sh
xmllint --c14n - | XMLLINT_INDENT=$'\t' xmllint --encode UTF-8 --format -
```

This way it works for TextWrangler 4 as well. The menu item to call the script has been moved to the `Text` menu in this version.

Reference link: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/textwrangler/FePYfNKi4rs

Answer (score 2):

I also used the method on http://magp.ie/2010/02/15/format-xml-with-textwrangler/

but I modified it because the errors I was getting regarding the xml I was attempting to format.  My script is just:

```
#!/bin/sh
xmllint "$*" | XMLLINT_INDENT=$'\t' xmllint --encode UTF-8 --format -
```

I took out the formatting for the W3C canonical format to fix my errors like yours.

Answer (score 2):

The script does not work still under 4.5.

I checked https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/textwrangler/FePYfNKi4rs
and it had a script that worked.

```
#!/bin/sh 

XMLLINT_INDENT=$'\t' xmllint --format --encode utf-8 -
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Mac, it may be easiest to create the script this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
pbpaste | xmllint --c14n - | XMLLINT_INDENT=$'\t' xmllint --encode UTF-8 --format - | pbcopy
```

Right-click the file, click Get Info, and change "Open With" to terminal. This will let you process xml in the primary clipboard from anywhere by clicking the icon. ie. copy-click-paste. You can also wrap with another so that it's accessible both ways.

```
pbpaste | ./tidy.sh | pbcopy # where tidy.sh is available to TextWrangler
```